# How to run a MySql script in Ubuntu?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm able to use MySql from the command line fine. I can create a db, add tables, add rows to tables, get queries etc.

What I can't do is write an sql file and run it.

From a regular terminal I change into the directory containing my script `test.sql`

Then I run `mysql -u root -p > test.mysql` and it asks me for my password. If I put the wrong password I get an error and if I put the correct password nothing happens, the terminal behaves as if its expecting further input.

If I have MySql started and I do

`mysql>SOURCE /home/ryan/MYSQL_Scripts/test.sql`

I get `Failed to open file '/home/ryan/MYSQL Scripts/test.sql', error: 2`

I know this means the file could not be found or supposedly does not exist yet from my explorer I right clicked on the file to get info on its path so I think the path is okay.

I don't think there's anything wrong with my script since I can run the commands individually from the mysql prompt. Here's my script:

```
USE first_db;

CREATE TABLE Department(id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE Employees(id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    department_id INT(6) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO Department (name) VALUES ("Fire");

SELECT * FROM Department;
```

I of course have a db, first_db, already created and am able to interact w/ it from the mysql prompt I just need help using mysql scripts.

Some advice would be much appreciated. Thanks!

`

Comment: You have a problem with your path.  Find out why and you solve your problem.

Comment: Flip your `>`:  `mysql -u root -p < test.mysql` Otherwise you are redirecting your stdout from mysql to that file (and blowing away it's content when you do so).

Answer (score 3):

JNevill's method worked right away, `mysql -u root -p < test1.sql` is the correct command to execute a mysql script from the command line.

Robert Harvey is onto something w/ the path reference. Not sure yet why the path I've used is incorrect though.